# jquery display decimals in val

Tags: jquery

I have the below syntax, each of these functions sets the value of an input box.

Discount, 1 decimal place
adjusted price, 2 decimal places (currency)

How do I show the decimal places with for each function.

```
   function calculateRow(row) {
        var price = +row.find('input[name^="adjustedprice"]').val();
        var qty = +row.find('input[name^="qty"]').val();
        row.find('input[name^="linetotal"]').val((price * qty).toFixed(2));
        var listprice = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();
        var discount = 0;
        var discount = Math.round(100 - (price / listprice) * 100);
        row.find('input[name^="discount"]').val(discount);
    }

    function calculateAjustedPrice(row) {
        var listprice = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();
        var discount = +row.find('input[name^="discount"]').val();
        var adjustedprice = Math.round((listprice/100)*(100-discount));
        row.find('input[name^="adjustedprice"]').val(adjustedprice);
        calculateRow(row);
        calculateGrandTotal();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the decimal places using fixed-point notation, using the [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method:

```
(number).toFixed(n); 
// where number is the value you want to format
// n is the decimal places you want
```

For example

```
var n = 12.8;
n.toFixed(2); // Returns 12.80 : note added zero
```